# How to Save Plotted Graph Data into Output Data File in Python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, output

Using matplotlib.pyplot, I plotted multiple wave functions w.r.t time series, showing the waves in multiple vertical axes, and output the graph in jpg using savefig. I want to know the easiest way in which I can output all wave functions into a single output data file maybe in CSV or DAT in rows and columns.

Comment: Please include plotting code

Answer (score 0):

How you plot the wave functions? Do you compute all the points?
If so, you can just write those points to csv.
You may refer to https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 0):

If you plotted the data using numpy array, you can use `numpy.savetxt`.